# Simple Nested Loop Issue. * Shape *

Tags: c++, nested-loops, shapes

I am having a brain shock right now so I wanted to ask very simple question.

Currenly, I am trying to print out starts like this

when input is 7 , the output is

```
* 
** 
* 
** 
* 
** 
*
```

and here my code is , it prints 14 times instead of 7 or when I put `N/2` it doesnt print the odd number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {


    int N;
    cout << " Please enter N " ;
    cin >> N;


    for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {

        cout << "*" << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

            cout << "*" ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what should it print for even numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each `N` you are printing two lines, with single `*` and another with two `*`. Instead just print single line with *either* one or two star based on the line is odd or even.

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  unsigned int N;
  cout << " Please enter N " ;
  cin >> N;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
      std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "**" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

(Untested code)

Comment: Yessir, I got the main idea. I should've checked whether its even or odd in my loop. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just go like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {

    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "**" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
}
```

In your case, for each of your N iterations, you print *, jump to a new line, print **, and then jump to a new iteration. So 14 lines when N is 7.

Comment: Yeah, thats the one. How could I just forget that, Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yeliz You're welcome. don't forget to accept an answer if you are satisfied with any.

Answer (score 1):

It's because each time the first `for` loop runs, the second loop also runs. You can't print out both `*` and `**` and expect it to print `N` times (it will always print `2 * N` times). You need to print either `*` or `**`, but not both at the same time. Simple example:

```
bool alternate = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {

    if (alternate) {
        cout << "*" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "**" << endl;
    }

    alternate = !alternate;
}
```

You could remove the `alternate` variable and check if `i` is even or odd (with something like `i & 1`), but I used the `alternate` variable to help make it clearer.

Comment: For example, when my N is odd , Ill just check (if N % 2 != 0) then Ill return false for the last loop of mine right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "return false", but if you mean returning early/breaking out of the loop early, then no, don't return false. Just loop for the full `N`. `N % 2 != 0` can tell you if you need to print `*` or `**`. It's not to be used to break out of the loop early.

Answer (score 0):

For each complete iteration of your outer loop the following is printed:

```
*
**
```

If you run that loop 7 times then you'll get 14 rows.  try this instead, no need for the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {          
    cout << "*" << endl;          
    cout << "**" << endl;     
}
```

Comment: But then it prints 2 lines when N is 1 , and 14 times just like my code.

Comment: Good spot, hadn't thought of that.